# Interpreting "svn diff" output

Tags: svn, diff

Let's say there is no content in a.c file, and then one modifies the file as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
```

Executing `svn diff`, I got this message.

```
--- b.c (revision 1)
+++ b.c (working copy)
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
+#include <stdio.h>
+
+int main()
+{
+    printf("Hello, world\n");
+}
```

Adding one more line in the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    printf("Goodbye, world\n");
}
```

This is the `svn diff` result:

```
--- b.c (revision 2)
+++ b.c (working copy)
@@ -3,4 +3,5 @@
 int main()
 {
     printf("Hello, world\n");
+    printf("Goodbye, world\n");
 }
```

I guess for old(-) and new(+) version, the number after comma is the line of total numbers shown. However, I'm not sure about the number before comma. I think it's where the change starts, but for the first case, the new(+) version has the number 1 not 0.

How one interprets the `svn diff` output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [Unified diff format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format) on Wikipedia:

> ```
> @@ -l,s +l,s @@ optional section heading
> ```
>
> The hunk range information contains two hunk ranges. The range for the
>   hunk of the original file is preceded by a minus symbol, and the range
>   for the new file is preceded by a plus symbol. Each hunk range is of
>   the format l,s where l is the starting line number and s is the number
>   of lines the change hunk applies to for each respective file. In many
>   versions of GNU diff, each range can omit the comma and trailing value
>   s, in which case s defaults to 1. Note that the only really
>   interesting value is the l line number of the first range; all the
>   other values can be computed from the diff.

Comment: Where does SVN document that it uses the unified diff format?

Answer (score 3):

> I think it's where the change starts, but for the first case, the new(+) version has the number 1 not 0.

Line numbers start at 1, so `1,6` for the new(+) file can be interpreted as you wrote: `1` is the starting line number and `6` is the number of lines shown.

The 0 for the line number must be a special case indicating the file didn't exist. That way you can differentiate between a non-existent old(-) file — `0,0` — and an empty one — `1,0`.